# Quader und Quadrat

Tags: etymology, mathematics

Was ist die Wortherkunft dieser beiden Wörter?

Ein 3-dimensionales *Quadrat* ist im Prinzip (sicherlich nicht mathematisch exakt) ein *Würfel*.

Dahingegen ist ein 3-dimensionales *Rechteck* ein *Quader*.

Woraus ergibt sich diese unterschiedliche Verwendung der Wörter "Quader/Quadrat"?

Answer (score 2):

[Laut DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Quader) stammt der Begriff "Quader" ursprünglich ab vom mittellateinischen *quadrus* oder *quadrus lapis,* „viereckiger Stein, Grundstein”. Dies wiederum leitet sich letztlich vom lateinischen Wort *quadrare,* „viereckig, ebenmäßig machen, passen” ab.

Von letzterem Wort [leitet sich letztlich auch das Word Quadrat ab,](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Quadrat) über den ebenfalls lateinischen Begriff *quadratus,* „viereckig.“

Die dreidimensionale Form „Quader“ ist also über dem Umweg des „viereckigen“ Steins in die Mathematik gekommen, während das „Quadrat“ sich direkt aus dem Begriff für „viereckig” entwickelt hat.

Comment: Richtic. Der *Quader* als Begriff für etwas Anfassbares (nämlich einfach einen behauenen Stein)  ist einfach früher in die deutsche Sprache eingewandert als das ein bißchen wissenschaftlichere und weniger alltagsgebräuchliche *Quadrat*. Aber beide stammen offensichtlich ursprünglich aus dem Lateinischen.